# I can't install cologram package. what is the correct way to install cologram python package?

Tags: python, colors

pip install cologram.py
Day 18  The Hirst Painting: pip download cologram.py
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cologram.py (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cologram.py
Day 18  The Hirst Painting: pip download cologram.py 1.2.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cologram.py (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cologram.py

how do I install cologram?
i cant even find on Pycharm

Comment: It's `colorgram.py`, not `cologram.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to check whether you have installed the pip installer.
run this code in the cmd prompt.

```
pip
```

**If pip is installed already then follow the steps below.**

```
pip install cologram.py
```

If this is also not working then go to this [link](https://pypi.org/project/colorgram.py/).
download the cologram.py file and it'll be installed.

You have to download the cologram rar file from  [here](https://pypi.org/project/colorgram.py/#files)

Extract the files to your python folder and now run the pip cmd in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

it colorgram on pycharm not cologram.

...The Current PyCharm  IDE does not recognizes 'colorgram' cologram. So you will have to say 'pip install colorgram.py' to be able to install package...